# Generate Typescript Interfaces from Java Interfaces

Tags: java, typescript

I have a Java server application, which uses Jackson to generically serialize DTO's using the reflection API. For example for this DTO interface:

```
package com.acme.library;
public interface Book { 
  com.acme.library.Author getAuthor();
  String getTitle();
}
```

From the POJO implementation of this interface, Jackson will generically serialize the following entity:

```
{
   "author": { "name": "F. Scott Fitzgerald"},
   "title": "The Great Gatsby"
}
```

This payload will be recieved using a HTTP GET from my TypeScript application, which is AngularJS-based:

```
$http.get("http://localhost/books/0743273567")
   .success((book: Book) => { ... });
```

So that I am able to use the strongly-typed nature of TypeScript, I find myself hand-coding the following typescript interface:

```
module com.acme.library {
  export interface Book {
      author: com.acme.library.Author;
      title: String;
  }
}
```

As a result, I have to maintain two copies of this same interface -- which is cumbersome at best. This gets particularly nasty, as I'd like to have the same javadoc/jsdoc comments on both interfaces, which involves a whole heap of copy&paste.

---

I would like to find a mechanism for automating this process.

Java is my main development language. As such, I'd like to find some tool which is capable of converting from the Java interface declaration (via the reflection API?) to the relevant TypeScript interface.

The only tool I have discovered in this domain is the NPM package `ts-java`. However, this is far too heavyweight for my use-case. It adds methods from the Object hierarchy to each interface, e.g. `hashCode()`, `wait()`, `getClass()`, etc.

Comment: I am currently looking for this too. Did you find something interesting?

Comment: @iberbeu -- Afraid not

Answer (score 33):

You can use [typescript-generator](https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator) as larslonne mentioned. It generates TypeScript interfaces from Java JSON classes. Some features you may find useful:

- Maven and Gradle plugin (can also be invoked directly from Java)
- Jackson 1 and Jackson 2
- collections, enums, inheritance, generics
- Javadoc comments to JSDoc comments
- detailed documentation (README, Wiki, Maven plugin)
- releases in Maven central repo

Here is example how to use it from Maven:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>cz.habarta.typescript-generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>typescript-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.25.322</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
                <jsonLibrary>jackson2</jsonLibrary>
                <classes>
                    <class>com.acme.library.Book</class>
                </classes>
                <outputFile>target/rest.d.ts</outputFile>
                <outputKind>module</outputKind>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Edit: Run it using `mvn process-classes` or using later phase like `mvn install`.
You can also pull `<configuration>` element two levels up and run `mvn typescript-generator:generate`.

Edit: I am the author of typescript-generator.

Comment: I tried to run the sample project but I got the following error: Description Resource Path Location Type
Could not find artifact cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-maven-plugin:jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT pom.xml /test line 1 Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: @DorCohen replace 1.7-SNAPSH‌​OT with latest version in maven central repository https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cz/habarta/typescript-generator/typescript-generator-maven-plugin. Currently it is 1.10.220.

Comment: When I'm updating to to 1.10.220 I;m getting the following error: 
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-maven-plugin:1.10.220:generate (execution: generate, phase: process-classes)

Comment: @DorCohen it seems this is some problem with your maven build configuration (pom.xml). Can you send me your pom.xml file? You can fill issue on github and I will try to help you.

Comment: @Vojita is there a way to configure the build so that each Object we convert goes to its own seperate .d.ts file. I couldn't see it in the documentation(maybe I missed it)

Comment: @KevinGleeson it's not possible, in single run it generates one file/module

Comment: @Vojita have you any plans to cater for mult file output? If not I may have a look and contribute to the projects :)

Comment: @Vojta, Can we use the typescript-generator from the CLI? Simply providing a Java file path and an output directory?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently working on a project with the same setup as yours: a Java API, and a Typescript web application.

We are using `cz.habarta.typescript-generator.typescript-generator-maven-plugin` to generate the `.d.ts` files when we build the API. The definition files are then packaged as an artifact with `<type>d.ts</type>`, using the `org.codehaus.mojo.build-helper-maven-plugin`. Lastly, the artifact is imported as a dependency in the web application, where the definition files are unpacked into the `target` directory.

This setup requires that you use maven for the web application, which isn't ideal, but it's a small price to pay for automatically generated definition files.

Answer (score 3):

I had great luck with [Amdatu TypeScript Generator](https://bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-typescript-generator/overview)

It can run in Gradle or standalone from the terminal (I used terminal, so that's what these instructions here are)

Simply clone the repo, run `./gradlew` to build it.

To execute it, I had to deviate a little from their instructions because there was no entry point in the jar (you wouldn't have this issue if you use a gradle build, because it would specify the entry class).

I used:

```
java -cp build/libs/org.amdatu.typescriptgenerator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.amdatu.typescriptgenerator.standalone.TypeScriptGeneratorStarter
```

It should then complain that there isn't a `typescript.settings.json` file, which it's expecting in the directory you are running the command from.

I'll include my own example because the linked repo's example settings file is a little unclear:

```
{
  "folder" : "/projectsfolder/project",
  "classFolder" : "target/classes",
  "output" : "typscriptOutputDirectory",
  "baseFolder" : "",
  "clearOutput" : false,
  "packages" : [
    ".*regexforwhatpackagesinsidetargetprojectshouldbeturnedintotypescript.*"
  ],
  "excludePackages" : [ ],
  "excludePattern" : [ ],
  "types" : { },
  "mapping" : { },
  "enumType" : "class",
  "classType" : "interface",
  "classPath" : [ ]
}
```

The most important fields in the settings are:

- `folder` is where your *already built* project is
- `classFolder` is where this generator will look inside that folder for compiled java classes
- `output` is the directory where the typescript definition files will be placed, relative to where you're executing the generator
- `packages` is a java regex for what packages should be turned into TypeScript definitions

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project with the goal to keep as simple as possible the transpiling process: [JavaModel-Converter](https://github.com/firegloves/JavaModel-Converter)

It works with the ide or simply by command line executing the jar present into dist folder.

All you need is to put your java model in the desired folder and to start transpile process.

I added also Angular style support.

Let's open issues if you have requests!

Theoretically my project is a general java model converter, but actually, only Typescript transpile is supported

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Script4J](https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/script4j) that is a set of libraries to code in TypeScript using Java API. Although this is a new project it can be useful.